# Store a random array in session to loop through on page reload

Tags: php, loops, session, cookies, reload

I have a PHP function that stores a random array in a session. It loops trough the array each time the page is reloaded. When the end of the array is reached it generates a new random array to loop through.

Instead of generating a new random array, is it possible to use the exact same random array that was generated on the first time visit?

```
// Init array
$files = array();

// Init session
session_start();

// Check if this is the first time visit or if there are files left to randomly select
if( !isset($_SESSION['FILES']) OR count($_SESSION['FILES']) == 0 ) {
    // Reload with all files
    $files = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
else {
    // Use the files that are left
    $files = $_SESSION['FILES'];
}

// Get random file
$selectedFile = array_rand($files);

// Include random file
print_r($files[$selectedFile]);

// Remove random file from array
unset($files[$selectedFile]);

// Set the session with the remaining files
$_SESSION['FILES'] = $files;
```

Comment: Save the original array in another session variable. When you reach the end of the array, set it back to this saved array.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It would be awesome if you provide me with some code—I am getting stuck …

Answer (score 0):

Use another session, probably called `$_SESSION['FILES_BACKUP']`;

When your array gets empty, copy the backup session to the main one.

```
// Init array
$files = array();


// Init session
session_start();

// Check if this is the first time visit or if there are files left to randomly select
if( !isset($_SESSION['FILES']) OR count($_SESSION['FILES']) == 0 ) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['FILES_BACKUP'])) {
        // Reload with all files
        echo 'no backup';
        $files = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    } else {
        echo 'backup';
        $_SESSION['FILES'] = $_SESSION['FILES_BACKUP'];
        $files = $_SESSION['FILES_BACKUP'];
    } 
    } else {
        // Use the files that are left
        $files = $_SESSION['FILES'];
    }

// Get random file
$selectedFile = array_rand($files);

// Include random file
print_r($files[$selectedFile]);

// Remove random file from array
unset($files[$selectedFile]);

// Set the session with the remaining files
$_SESSION['FILES'] = $files;
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you post the whole code—I didn’t manage to bring it to work.

Comment: I might have done a mistake in the code. I'll give it a try and post it entirely.

Comment: You're not setting `$files` in the `else` block.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I also did some weird stuff with the brackets :)

Comment: Many thanks! I’ve tested your code but it still does not do what I like: When the first loop is over, it always starts again with »no backup« and generates a new random order. Do you have a clue why?